# calling angularjs scope function from href link from cshtml file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is cshtml contents:

```
@model MBOS.DTO.ViewModel.Others.ReportTemplateViewModel<MBOS.DTO.ViewModel.BranchBOCAAnalysis>

@if (Model.IncludeTableHeader)
{<thead>
    <tr class="no-borders">

        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Branch</th>
        <th>Assessor</th>
        <th>Rating</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
}

@foreach (var row in Model.Models)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@row.Id</td>
        <td>@row.Branch</td>
        <td>@row.Assessor</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:angular.element(document.getElementById('branchAnalysisCtrl')).scope().RatingDetail();">@row.Rating.FormatDouble() </a></td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is AngularJs Controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module("app.branchAnalysis", ["app.base.report"])
    .controller('branchAnalysisCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
        'appStore', '$controller', '$routeParams', 'Restangular', 'toaster',
        '$location', '$q', '$filter',
  function ($scope, $http, appStore, $controller, $routeParams, Restangular, toaster, $location, $q, $filter) {
 $scope.RatingDetail = function () {
          debugger;
          restangular.one("dashboard/" + (type === 'b' ? 'boca' : 'aoca') + "/assessment/rating/" + assessment.BranchId + "/" + assessment.AssessmentMonth).get().then(function (response) {
              if (type === 'b')
                  $scope.bocaStatusPieViewModel.RatingItems = response.plain();
              else
                  $scope.aocaStatusPieViewModel.RatingItems = response.plain();
          });
      }
   }]);
  })();
```

I am trying to call RatingDetail() function from the href link as mentioned in the above cshtml.
I tried with ng-click but also not worked. I need some good and working examples.  I am waiting for exact solutions.

Comment: you are trying to call a client side script from the server side;  this is never going to work.  it's not really clear why using `ng-click` didn't work for you, because you aren't even showing where this HTML snippet lives in your full document structure and if it even has access to the controller in question.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you tried to get it working with `ng-click` but it didn't work, what issue did you have?

See primitive JSFiddle example with working ng-click http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/12116/

Comment: I implemented in the same way as u mentioned in the above. Now it does not give any error but still didn't call the functions.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console if you inspect the page?